# How can I create different index patterns based on different applications using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a java application running which will send its logs to logstash, it is based on this tutorial http://www.andrew-programming.com/2018/09/18/integrate-springboot-application-with-elk-and-filebeat/

My question is if I want to separate my logs from different applications I would like to to use a different index pattern for each app rather than have them all in the same one..

Here is my logstash config file where index => "app-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"  is the name of the pattern.

I have tried stuff like %{type} %{tags} [tags] [type] but none of them print any variable relating to the apps.. i can use host in the index pattern but do not wish to use ip adresses in the index patter as they might change.

```
input {
  tcp {
  port => 4560
  codec => json_lines
  }
  beats {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "5044"
  }
}
output{
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "app-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"  
  document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you collect the different log files using filebeat? If so, you can add a specifica tag to each `filebeat.input` and create filters using this tag to add a new field with the index pattern name, and then use this field in your output.

Answer (score 0):

added the following to logback.spring.xml

```
<encoder charset="UTF-8" class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
  <customFields>{"appname":"auxiliary-service-application"}</customFields>
</encoder>
```

In logstash.conf file used the parameter.

```
output{
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "%{appname}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"   
  document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helpful

Ex:

```
input {
 file {
    path => "C:/_Logs/*.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    add_field => {
     "log_origin" => "XYZ" 
    }    
}
file {
    path => "C:/_Data/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    add_field => { 
     "log_origin" => "ABC" 
    }
}
output {
  if (  "XYZ" in [log_origin] ) {
   elasticsearch {
           hosts => "10.0.0.0:9200"
           index => "deploy-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
   }
 }
   else {
   elasticsearch {
           hosts => "10.0.0.0:9200"
           index => "validator-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
   }
 }
}
```